Isn't it a must to use a mutex for each singleton instance access
I was reading about the Singleton design pattern and how to implement it thread-safe.
All went well until the authors said: "In reality, we need a lock only when initializing instance. That should occur only the first time instance is called"
and this is the implementation:
    Singleton* Singleton::instance() 
{
  if (instance == nullptr) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (instance == nullptr) {
        Singleton* temp = new Singleton;
        instance = temp;
    }
  }
  return instance;
}

But I am concerned about saying that we only need a mutex while creating the instance. WHY?
Consider a case when you have a method inside the singleton class that modifies a common value based on a previous one. Am I right?
For example:
thread#1: gets the instance and calls a method that multiplies a common variable by 2. but gets interrupted by thread#2 after getting the value of common var and before modification.
thread#2: gets the instance and calls a method that multiplies the same common var by 3. but It has the old value. thread#2 finishes and updates the common var.
thread#1: is back and performs his calculations neglecting the thread#2 changes.
void thread1(){
   Singleton.GetInstance().Multiply2();
}

void thread2(){
   Singleton.GetInstance().Multiply3();
}

This issue may happen if we consider using mutexes only if there isn't an Instance.

Just check this, it's not necessary.

this is outdated, uses a Meyers Singleton: Singleton& get_instance() { static Singleton s; return s; } 100% thread safe.

If the singleton object have shared internal state, then yes you need to protect that with some kind of lock (or use lockless data structures). Which is one of the reasons singletons aren't used that much, and when used they are usually stateless or used only in single-threaded systems.

If your singleton has state you need to make the mutating functions thread safe if you want them to be thread safe out of the box.

@πάνταῥεῖ Can the accepted answer to the Question you've provided help in the case I have provided at the end of the Question? take a 2nd look I've edited it.

@AliK. Would you accept a duplicate? The specific functions must be designed thread-safe, not accessing the Singleton object itself.

Double checked locking belongs to software history books. Initialization of a Meyer singleton is now handled safely and automatically by the compiler. However accessing the object is not thread safe. You may implement a protection pattern for that. Further more, I would also wrap the Meyer singleton inside a monostate class, so it looks like ordinary objects.
